# Access radii characterizing rings in a PieChart3D for multiple datasets

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

Consider the following code:

```
PieChart3D[{{0.49, 0.33, 0.18},
  {0.47, 0.39, 0.15}, {0.45, 0.44, 0.09}}, 
 SectorOrigin -> {{Pi, "Clockwise"}, 12}, SectorSpacing -> Medium]
```

[image]

Is there a way in which I can make the inner and outer rings narrower than the central ring? In other words can one access individually the radii specifying each one of the three rings within the PieChart3D command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`SectorChart3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SectorChart3D.html):

[image]

```
{r1, r2, r3} = {1, 3, 1};

SectorChart3D[{Thread[{{0.49, 0.33, 0.18}, r1, 1}], 
  Thread[{{0.47, 0.39, 0.15}, r2, 1}], 
  Thread[{{0.45, 0.44, 0.09}, r3, 1}]}, 
 SectorOrigin -> {{Pi, "Clockwise"}, 12}, 
 SectorSpacing -> Medium, 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: That's great! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @DanieleBinosi, my pleasure.